# php remove empty paragraphs

Tags: php, json, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to remove empty paragraphs from a string.
Yes, I know it sounds pretty easy, but it just won't work. I have tried many solutions that I read here on the forum, but neither of them will work.
I should probably add that I get the strings that I want to convert from an array which is created from a json-file.
Here's my code:

```
if ($json_file = json_decode(file_get_contents("export.json"), true)) {
    $str = $json_file[12]["the_string"];
}
echo $str;
```

When I look at the source code of the page I see:

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p>Some text, Some text</p>
```

Now I want to get rid of only the empty paragraphs.
I have tried this:

```
echo preg_replace("/<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>/", '', $str);
```

...but it doesn't work. Neither does this far more simple solution:

```
echo str_replace("<p> </p>","",$str);
```

Trying both of the solutions above, the output is exactly the original string.
Any help would be highly appreciated, as I have been searching the forum for half a day now...
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
It has to do something with the format of the string that I get from the array. For testing I just copy/pasted the output into the following and here it works absolutely fine!

```
$str2 = "
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Some text, Some text</p>";

echo preg_replace("/<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>/", '', $str2);
```

EDIT2: This is the actual content being accessed in the json file:

```
<p>\u00a0<\/p>\n<p>\u00a0<\/p>\n<p>\u00a0<\/p>\n<p>This is some text<\/p>
```

Comment: what do you think `[\s|&nbsp;]` does?

Comment: Try this regexp `<p>[\n ]*?</p>` there is a space after \n

Comment: it should detect whitespaces or none breaking spaces, shouldn't it?

Comment: `<p>[\n ]*?<\/p>` works as well. As I said, all the regular expressions I tried, should work! I tested them on Rubular.com. Ther must be something else, that is wrong, I don't think it's the regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a bit of reading about UTF-8, Unicode and lots of other stuff, I found a working solution (actually here on the forum).

```
echo str_replace("<p>\xc2\xa0</p>","",$str);
```

Nice and easy. But as `\x2a\xa0` is just a `nbsp;` I still don't get why this *didn't* work: `<p>&nbsp;</p>`...